# Prove that $S ∪\{v\} = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v\}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $Ax = b$ be a nonhomogeneous linear system with a particular solution $v$. Let $S = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ be a basis for the solution space of the corresponding homogeneous system $Ax = 0$. Prove that $S ∪\{v\} = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v\}$ is linearly independent.

Not sure if this is correct but since $S$ is a basis for the solution space of the homogeneous system $Ax = 0$, we know that $S$ is linearly independent.

Furthermore, since $v$ is a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous system $Ax = b$, it cannot be written as a linear combination of the vectors in $S$, because if it could, it would also be a solution of the homogeneous system.

Therefore, $S ∪ \{v\} = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v\}$ is linearly independent because none of the vectors in the set can be written as a linear combination of the others.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: All looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything you said is correct.
You could also do it from another way, think that you have $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4,\alpha_5 \in K$ such that
$$
\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3+\alpha_4v_4+\alpha_5v=0$$
Then:
$$\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=\alpha_4=\alpha_5=0$$